# Вставка данных на страницу с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

На странице есть блок `<div class="trading__buy-text" id="BS_title_balance"></div>` В который текстом нужно динамически подгружать данные из БД
Делаю следующим образом:

```
<script>

setInterval(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
            url: "trade_total.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {refresh:true}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    $('.book__table_history').html(function(){
                        var res = '';
                        res += '<div class="trading__buy-text" id="BS_title_balance">'+(result.Volume['value'][i]/1).toFixed(8)+'</div>';

                                }
                        }
                        return res;
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                $('.book__table_history').html(function(){
                    var res='';
                    return res;
                });
            }
    });
}, 1000); 
</script>
```

Файл trade_total:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','ON');
session_start();
include_once('db_connect.php');

if ($_POST['refresh'] == "true") {
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(`total`) AS value FROM `orders` WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY dttm_close_order DESC LIMIT 30 ");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $Volume['value'][]      = $row["value"];   
    $out = array(
        'Volume' => $Volume
    );
    // Устанавливаем заголовот ответа в формате json
    header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

    // Кодируем данные в формат json и отправляем
    echo json_encode($out);

    //Прекращаем выполнения скрипта
    die;
}
```

Но информация в блоке не обновляется

Comment: Замените echo на return, уберите die(); в error ловите xhr и консольте его, header в trade_total устанавливать не обязательно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обновлять информацию в DOM'E уже после записи данных в переменную:

```js
success: function(result) {
  if (result) {
    var res = '<div class="trading__buy-text" id="BS_title_balance">' + (result.Volume['value'][i] / 1).toFixed(8) + '</div>';

    $('.book__table_history').html(res);
  }
  return res;
},
```

Да и просто можно попробовать вывести переменную `res` в консоль в качестве отладки.